# Codeigniter HTTP Error 500 from model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter.  I'm trying to create a simple customer database and when it keeps trying to load my update_customer model It keeps giving me a Http error 500.  I'm pretty sure I've narrowed it down to the model cause when I comment out the model call the page redirects it to itself with no error.  Any ideas where my mistake was?

and I can't seem to find the error in the apache error logs...

CONTROLLER:

```
function edit_customer($id){
    $data['success']=0;
    if($_POST){
        $data_customer=$_POST;
        $data_customer['active'] = 1;
        $this->customer->update_customer($id,$data);
        $data['success']=1;
    }
    $data['customer']=$this->customer->get_customer($id);

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('edit_customer',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

MODEL:

```
function get_customer($id){
    $this->db->select()->from('customers')->where(array('active'=>1, 'id'=>$id))->order_by('date_added', 'desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->first_row('array');
}

function update_customer($id, $data){
    $this->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('customers', $data);
}
```

Comment: 500 is an Apache error, check the Apache error logs.

Comment: Post your entire model, including the class. Also, this might seem silly, but you sure you have `<?php` at the top?

Comment: @Dagon, 500 is not an Apache error specifically... just that an error occurred with something Apache was doing.  Almost always on a PHP application, PHP is the source of the error.  I think that's what you meant... just posting here for Tyler's benefit.

Comment: true an HTTP error code not Apache specific.

Comment: Calling `$this->db->select()` without any parameter is redundant. Might as well omit that function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a `db->` in your where statement  should be:

```
function update_customer($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('customers', $data);
}
```